# Detect when a material was assigned in script

Tags: python

I'm working on an Addon and need to run a function every time the user assigns a Material to a Material Slot or creates a new one. I tried using the message bus with the following code:

```py
import bpy

handle = object()

sub_to = bpy.types.MaterialSlot

#(those two don't work either)
#sub_to = bpy.context.object.material_slots
#sub_to = bpy.context.object.material_slots[0]

def notify_test(*args):
    print("changed Material!")

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=sub_to, 
    owner=handle, args=(), 
    notify=notify_test,
)

bpy.msgbus.publish_rna  (key=sub_to )
```

But this never fires. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Sadly the documentation on `Message Bus` is quite thin.

Comment: yes that's what made me sad as well.. they don't have enough examples in their documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Run when a material is assigned on an object (But not run when slot is removed)

```
import bpy
        
def msgbus_callback():
    print(bpy.context.object)

owner = 'owner'

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=(bpy.types.Object, 'active_material'),
    owner=owner,
    args=(),
    notify=msgbus_callback
)
```

Comment: Amazing thanks a lot :)