# Include OS Module functions on depsgraph handler executions

Tags: python

Depsgraph handlers don't seem to support execution of any function outside of the bpy module (unless I'm missing a way to do this?). Is there any way to extend this functionality to python's OS module so I can interact with the filesystem? I'm trying to make a depsgraph handler generate a text file when a specific StringProperty is edited in the UI panel I created.

Comment: This might not be a very good idea - depsgraph update might happen hundreds of times per second. Try using [Application Timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html)

Comment: Thank you! This might actually be what I'm looking for. Though, the depsgraph handler would execute a script that's restricted by an if statement, so it will only execute one time under those specific conditions. Do you think this is still the best option?

Comment: I don't know what's best. I don't even know why creating a file would fail or why it would need os module. As far as I know it would work fine even from depsgraph update handler and you don't need os module for it. See: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp . This might be of interest for checking when some property is updated: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268523/detect-when-a-material-was-assigned-in-script  also see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

Comment: Why don't you use the StringProperty update to trigger when it is updated ?

Comment: Is this what you're referring to?
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: This was really informative. I found out that both of your suggestions actually work, and the best option was to use the StringProperty update method, which I didn't get to yet in the documentation. The issue I was having was actually created by errors that weren't being reported back to the system console. Because they weren't being reported in the console, I didn't catch it, but try except fixed that issue. In the future, I'm just going to make an operator and execute the script on button press until I get the desired result, then assign a callback.