# Handle when material is dragged and dropped onto object

Tags: python

I need to handle some special steps for my material system, when a material is assigned.
[I've followed this tip so far](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268523/detect-when-a-material-was-assigned-in-script), and it works well if assigning through the properties UI. It does not work when dragging and dropping a material from the Asset browser, which i'd love to handle as well. Seems Blender [has been dragging their feet to support this for 10 years](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/39625), and I suspect my only chance to get this to work, is through a depsgraph update post handler?

Comment: Just some info for those ever looking:
-Track changes from depsgraph_update_post.
-Keep a global dict of obj - material pairs for the previous state
-if a change happens in an update, you have a list of changed objects
-because it's tricky to run code in the handler, I had to make an operator on a very short timer that forces context to window, and makes changes.
(ChatGPT was very helpful in figuring this out btw.. credit where it's due)